# problem with Greek in beamer (windows)

Tags: beamer, windows, greek

I am trying to write my thesis presentation in windows with Beamer but i have an issue with Greek language.

when i want to add a definition from drop down menu , the letters dont appear right in the compiled file.

for example if i add Definition , in the compiled pdf appear Δεφινιτιον instead of Ορισμος (Definition in Greek).

Comment: If you're using dropdowns, it would help to let us know what editor you are using - it looks to me like the editor isn't aware of Greek, but is just transliterating the English word.

Comment: I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You have to pass the `greek` option to `beamer` in the `\documentclass` line. If you have a solution, then add it in the "Answers" space.

Comment: it was a temporary solution only for the definition.

Comment: Generally I have to write every word in greeklish in order to have greek. For example if I want the greek word "ορισμός" I have to write " orism'oc" which takes a lifetime!

Comment: this is what I have. Is there any way to write straight in greek?                                    \documentclass[slidestop]{beamer}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}

% Load a theme (graphics , colors ,...) for the presentation
\usepackage{beamerthemeboxes} %new

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass the `greek` option to the class:

```
\documentclass[greek]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
Η Αθήνα είναι η πρωτεύουσα της Ελλάδα
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The definition is printed on english like this "Orismo'oc". How can I fix it?

Comment: @adosar Not in my example code. You probably have something else going on.

Comment: I just copy-paste your code that is why I asked.

Comment: @adosar Just for safety, I copied it from here and rerun it: I have no issue at all. What TeX distribution and version are you running?

Comment: Miktex 4.2. The strange thing is that \begin{proof} works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Try and use the following with xelatex

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Languages
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage[Greek,Latin]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionsForGreek{\setlanguage{greek}}{\setlanguage{english}}

%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fonts
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % substitute with any font that exists on your system
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro} % substitute with any font that exists on your system
\setmonofont{Consolas} % substitute with any font that exists on your system

%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Beamer Stuff
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{Παρουσίαση διπλωματικής}  
\author{Κώστας Παπαδόπουλος}
\date{Σεπτέμβριος 2013} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\section{Κεφάλαιο 1ο}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Αυτό είναι το 1ο κεφάλαιο} 
Συμπληρώνεις ανάλογα! 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing the complete version of Miktex the following worked for me: I created a folder. In it I saved as greekslides.sty the following

```
\ProvidesPackage{common}


\usepackage{subfiles}


\usepackage{fontspec}


\AtBeginDocument{
\mathcode`α=\alpha
\mathcode`β=\beta
\mathcode`γ=\gamma 
\mathcode`Γ=\Gamma
\mathcode`δ=\delta
\mathcode`Δ=\Delta
\mathcode`ε=\epsilon
\mathcode`ζ=\zeta
\mathcode`η=\eta
\mathcode`θ=\theta
\mathcode`Θ=\Theta
\mathcode`ι=\iota
\mathcode`κ=\kappa
\mathcode`λ=\lambda
\mathcode`Λ=\Lambda
\mathcode`μ=\mu
\mathcode`ν=\nu
\mathcode`ξ=\xi
\mathcode`Ξ=\Xi
\mathcode`π=\pi
\mathcode`Π=\Pi
\mathcode`ρ=\rho
\mathcode`σ=\sigma
\mathcode`Σ=\Sigma
\mathcode`τ=\tau
\mathcode`υ=\upsilon
\mathcode`φ=\phi
\mathcode`Φ=\Phi
\mathcode`χ=\chi
\mathcode`ψ=\psi
\mathcode`Ψ=\Psi 
\mathcode`ω=\omega
\mathcode`Ω=\Omega 
}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }


\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Calibri}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}[theorem]{Ορισμός}
```

Then I saved in the same folder the following code as anyname.tex.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{greekslides}
\begin{document}
\title{Not a presentation}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Ελληνικά στον beamer}
  Είναι εφικτό να γράφεις μαθηματικά κατευθείαν στα ελληνικά
  $$ G_{μν}=8πT_{μν}$$ 
  Επίσης μπορείς να περνάς από τα ελληνικά στα αγγλικά χωρίς ενδιάμεσες εντολές: english-ελληνικά-english-ελληνικά, κ.ο.κ. (i.e. etc.)

Ακολουθεί ένας ορισμός  
\begin{mydef}
Έστω ορισμός.
\end{mydef}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It seems to work.

P.S. I suppose that many Latex users in Europe would feel more comfortable if they could just switch from Greek to Latin directly from the keyboard both in mathmode and textmode. So there must be already some package on this.